# PynamoDB Single Table Design OrgsAndUsers

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, pynamodb

I am trying to create this single table using pynamodb:

[image]

This is what I have for the OrgModel:

```
TABLE_NAME = 'OrgsAndUsers'


class OrgModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        table_name = TABLE_NAME
        region = 'us-east-1'
    OrgName = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True, range_key=True)
    SubscriptionLevel = UnicodeAttribute()
```

How do I model the User object? How do I set `OrgModel` as the User's partition key?

Is pynamodb a good package to use for dynamodb programming in python?

Comment: Have you tried with Pynamodb's [documentation](https://pynamodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#creating-a-model)? Also, whether or not Pymanodb is a good package will probably result in answers based on personal opinions.

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking to do is

```
class UserModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'OrgsAndUsers'
        region = 'us-east-1'
    org_name = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    user_name = UnicodeAttribute(range_key=True)
    subscription_level = UnicodeAttribute()
    role = UnicodeAttribute()
```